# Clean Architecture and Asp.net Identity

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity, clean-architecture, onion-architecture

I'm playing around with Clean Architecture and have the following project layout

- Domain (Entities, Exceptions, enums etc.)
- Application (CQRS and interfaces for external stuff "get me stuff from somewhere", "send an email" etc)
- Infrastructure (ef core stuff, send email implementation etc)
- UI (simple razor pages app)

I want to use asp.net identity for authentication / authorisation so wanted to define an AppUser class within domain project but I cant because then that would mean adding a reference to "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" which to my understanding goes against clean architecture. The Domain layer should have no external references is what I've read in multiple places.

I'm currently toying with the idea of adding a new assembly Infrastructure.Security and have all of the security related code housed in there. Then any domain item that needed a user association would just have a new field `UserId`, I would still define all of the required interfaces within the Application layer and this new Infrastructure.Security layer would just implement said interface(s). It seems to fit with the clean architecture ethos because should I want to swap out asp.net identity for another technology its just a case of replacing this Infrastructure.Security.

Has anyone else run into the same issue, does my solution seem like a sensible approach?

I'm open to suggestions and / or better ideas, I must admit I'm completely new to Clean Architecture but like what I have seen and can see the merit behind it.

Comment: You are right to say it should not be in your Domain. The question is, does a User entity make sense in your Domain ? If so, it should be a Domain entity as any other and not be linked to authentication/authorization. These should be handled by your UI and/or Application projects. Your Application project could determine the (domain) User using the authenticated user. Finally if you want to link your entities to the authenticated user for some audit needs (entity creator, last modifier, etc.) that should be your Infrastructure project job.

Comment: Sorry about the delay getting back to you on this, the User entity does make sense as a domain entity in my app so I'll create a standard Poco User class and the handle the Auth stuff in the higher layers linking the domain user to the Auth user.